# C : Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error

Tags: c, struct, dereference

I created a link list of contacts in C. It worked fine. but now I want to write a delete function for a specified contact (by name) I get the `Error:"dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"`. Here is my code:

```
struct contact
{
    char name[100];
    char number[20];
    struct contact *next;
};
int deleteByName(struct contact **hptr, char *name)
{
    struct student *prev = NULL;
    struct student *temp = *hptr;
    while (strcmp(temp->name /*The Error is Here*/ , name) != 0 && (temp->next) != NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next; 
    }
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0)
    {
        if (prev == NULL)
            *hptr = temp->next;
        else
            prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nNAME '%s' WAS NOT FOUND TO BE DELETED.", name);
    return -1;
}
```

I wanted to know why i get this error (despite defining struct contact.). Thank you.

Comment: Probably because you define `struct contact`, but `temp` is defined as a pointer to `struct student`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Sadly, you don't present enough code for us to be able to help you with your problem properly. Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `next` pointer type was `contact` - assuming that was a typo - here's the corrected code with the typos fixed - This compiles- HTH!

```
struct student
{
    char name[100];
    char number[20];
    struct student *next;
};

int deleteByName(struct student **hptr, char *name)
{
    struct student *prev = NULL;
    struct student *temp = *hptr;
    while (strcmp(temp->name, name) != 0 && (temp->next) != NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next; //***No Error now***
    }
    if (strcmp(temp->name, name) == 0)
    {
        if (prev == NULL)
            *hptr = temp->next;
        else
            prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\nNAME '%s' WAS NOT FOUND TO BE DELETED.", name);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that part was OK, I made a mistake in showing the Error line. I corrected it now.

Comment: You have defined `struct student *temp` can you post your declaration of `student`?

Comment: "Struct student" is a type itself, I defined it at the top.

Comment: When you say `struct student *temp = *hptr;` you are basically instantiating a pointer of type `student`. You need to declare ` struct student`  somewhere

Comment: Isn't this the decleration(which i made at the top of the code)?: 
struct student
{
    char name[100];
    char number[20];
    struct student *next;
};

Comment: But your code says `struct contact
{
    char name[100];
    char number[20];
    struct contact *next;
};`

Comment: that was so stupid :)))))))) thank you for your help.